# Remover elementos de dataset por fatores

Tags: r

Considerando um *dataset*:

```
set.seed(1)
fatores = sample(1:12, 30, replace = T)
x = matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 2)
dataset = cbind(fatores, x)
dataset = data.frame(dataset)
dataset$fatores = as.factor(dataset$fatores)
```

Quero remover as linhas cujos número de fatores sejam menor igual a 2. No exemplo acima, o fator 1, removeria a linha 10 e 27.
Como posso realizar este procedimento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa complicar muito para fazer isso, você tem apenas que contar as ocorrências de cada level usando table e depois remover as linhas em que as ocorrências são menores que o limite. Por exemplo:

```
tb <- table(dataset$fatores)
rem <- !(dataset$fatores %in% names(tb[tb <= 2]))
dataset[rem, ]

#    fatores          V2          V3
# 2        5 -0.01619026  0.36458196
# 4       11  0.82122120 -0.11234621
# 5        3  0.59390132  0.88110773
# 6       11  0.91897737  0.39810588
# 7       12  0.78213630 -0.61202639
# 8        8  0.07456498  0.34111969
# 9        8 -1.98935170 -1.12936310
# 11       3 -0.05612874  1.98039990
# 12       3 -0.15579551 -0.36722148
# 14       5 -0.47815006  0.56971963
# 18      12  0.38767161  0.68973936
# 19       5 -0.05380504  0.02800216
# 21      12 -0.41499456  0.18879230
# 22       3 -0.39428995 -1.80495863
# 23       8 -0.05931340  1.46555486
# 26       5 -0.16452360  0.47550953
# 28       5  0.69696338  0.61072635
# 29      11  0.55666320 -0.93409763
# 30       5 -0.68875569 -1.25363340
```

Nesse caso, todas as linhas dos fatores `c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10)` foram removidas.

Você pode aplicar a mesma lógica de outras formas. Usando `sapply` para criar um vetor com a contagem, e depois filtrar por ele:

```
rem <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), function(i) {
  sum(dataset$fatores[i] == dataset$fatores)
}) > 2
dataset[rem, ]
```

Ou usando `dplyr`, contando linha a linha quantas vezes aquele fator ocorre e utilizando isso como critério para o filtro.

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% rowwise() %>% filter(sum(fatores == .$fatores) > 2)
```

Uma dica: Quando for criar variáveis aleatórias que não devam representar números, é melhor utilizar letras, pra facilitar a interpretação dos resultados. No seu caso, poderia ser `letters[1:12]`.

Comment: São de fato fatores, deveria ter sido mais claro, esses fatores são nomes, por exemplo, "MLP", "KFC" etc. neste caso a forma sugerida não funciona.

Comment: @WagnerJorge Se são fatores com texto, como você quer verificar se ele é "menor que ou igual a 2"? Não faz sentido. Você quer dizer que ocorre menos duas ou menos vezes?

Comment: Explicando melhor, quero verificar se a quantidade daquele fator é menor que 2. No exemplo acima acontece "1" duas vezes aí removo suas posições. Poderia ser 5, se ele acontecesse 2 vezes aí removia suas posições também.

Comment: @WagnerJorge Pronto, refiz a resposta de acordo com sua explicação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim também:

```
> dataset %>% 
+   group_by(fatores) %>%
+   summarise(n = n()) %>%
+   filter(n > 2) %>%
+   left_join(dataset, by = "fatores") %>%
+   select(-n)
Source: local data frame [19 x 3]

   fatores          V2          V3
    (fctr)       (dbl)       (dbl)
1        3  0.59390132  0.88110773
2        3 -0.05612874  1.98039990
3        3 -0.15579551 -0.36722148
4        3 -0.39428995 -1.80495863
5        5 -0.01619026  0.36458196
6        5 -0.47815006  0.56971963
7        5 -0.05380504  0.02800216
8        5 -0.16452360  0.47550953
9        5  0.69696338  0.61072635
10       5 -0.68875569 -1.25363340
11       8  0.07456498  0.34111969
12       8 -1.98935170 -1.12936310
13       8 -0.05931340  1.46555486
14      11  0.82122120 -0.11234621
15      11  0.91897737  0.39810588
16      11  0.55666320 -0.93409763
17      12  0.78213630 -0.61202639
18      12  0.38767161  0.68973936
19      12 -0.41499456  0.18879230
```

Achei interessando fazer um benchmark de todas as soluções. A ordem que coloquei aqui é:

- sol1: primeira solução do @molx, usando apenas base
- sol2: segunda solução do @molx, usando `sapply`
- sol3: terceira solução do @molx, usando `dplyr`
- sol4: solução do @Wagner Jorge
- sol5: minha solução usando dplyr

Os resultados estão abaixo:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval   cld
 sol1  214.468  241.1875  259.3642  255.521  273.039  381.158   100 a    
 sol2 2437.349 2586.5195 2770.6785 2665.087 2733.745 4688.896   100   c  
 sol3 3200.015 3373.2525 3574.7309 3505.259 3658.677 5173.747   100     e
 sol4 3072.610 3234.3445 3386.9734 3349.010 3432.178 4997.856   100    d 
 sol5 1526.396 1640.8840 1742.2747 1721.752 1807.574 3616.563   100  b
```

---

```
Abaixo o código completo para refazer o benchmark.

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  sol1 = {tb <- table(dataset$fatores)
  rem <- !(dataset$fatores %in% names(tb[tb <= 2]))
  dataset[rem, ]},
  sol2 = {rem <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), function(i) {
    sum(dataset$fatores[i] == dataset$fatores)
  }) > 2
  dataset[rem, ]},
  sol3 = {dataset %>% rowwise() %>% filter(sum(fatores == .$fatores) > 2)},
  sol4 = {remove_fatores(dataset,2)},
  sol5 = {dataset %>% 
      group_by(fatores) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      filter(n > 2) %>%
      left_join(dataset, by = "fatores") %>%
      select(-n)}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pensando aqui cheguei na seguinte função. Não é muito rápida, mas serve.

```
#numero_minimo no exemplo é 2
remove_fatores = function(dataset1, numero_minimo){
  fatores = dataset1[,1]
  for(i in 1 : length(fatores)){
    if(length(which(fatores == fatores[i])) <= numero_minimo){
      dataset1 = dataset1[-which(fatores == fatores[i]), ]
    }
  }
  return(dataset1)
}
```